# How to import images from the external URL in Magento2

Tags: magento2

After Adding this code

```
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
     $currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();

    $mediaUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
    $currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
    $image_url  = $importData['addtional_image']; 
    $image_type = substr(strrchr($image_url,"."),1); 
    $filename   = md5($image_url .$image_type;
    $filepath   = $mediaUrl . $filename;
    file_put_contents($filepath, file_get_contents(trim($image_url))); 
    $mediaAttribute = array (
            'thumbnail',
            'small_image',
            'image'
    );
```

Facing the issue failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

Answer (score 0):

Acording to your code you are trying to save image to HTTP path.

Just use relative or absolute server path to media image directory.

```
$fileSystem = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
$mediaPath = $fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
```

Then use it to save your file.

```
$filepath = $mediaPath . $filename;
file_put_contents($filepath, file_get_contents(trim($image_url)));
```

This could be your final script

```
$fileSystem = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
$mediaPath = $fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();

$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();

$mediaUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();

$image_url  = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/magento/Img/logo.svg?v=39db58a118b2";
$image_path_info = pathinfo(parse_url($image_url)["path"]);

$image_type = substr(strrchr($image_url,"."),1);

$filename   = md5($image_url . $image_type) . "." . $image_path_info["extension"];

$filepath = $mediaPath . "/" . $filename;
file_put_contents($filepath, file_get_contents(trim($image_url)));
```

You can find your file in directory `pub/media`.

Comment: I have tried the above url , not working

Answer (score 0):

This should work :)

```
 function uploadImages( $imagepath, $product_sku)
{
    global $objectManager;
    global $terminator;

    $productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');   
    $productID = $productRepository->getIdBySku($product_sku);
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $strs=$storeManager->getStores();
        
    if ($productID != 0)
    {        
       $_product = $productRepository->load($productID);  
       $_product->setStoreId(0)->addImageToMediaGallery($imagepath, array('image', 'small_image','swatch'),  false, false);
       $_product->save();        
    }

    unset($_product);  
}
```